Kotlin Mockk what is the difference between `just runs` and `answer {}`?
Given a function foo of an object Bar:
fun foo(){
    // some logic
}

Using Mockk, in the test of an object that uses Bar, I often see answers {} to specify (with every) the return of foo:
internal class FooBarTest {
    private val barMock = mockk<Bar>()

    // ...
    @Test
    fun `test something`() = runTest {
        every { barMock.foo() } answers {}
        //...
    }
}

I would have used just runs, and using just runs in this situation instead of answers {} works fine.
What is the difference between answers {} and just runs ?

There is no functional difference. It's purely stylish, maybe answers {} is more in-line with rest of the code or it's going to create less diff when someone decides to put something inside of the answer.
